# Выбор кодировки для логирования в java на Linux

Tags: java, linux

Для логирования использую java.util.logging.Logger и java.util.logging.Formatter. 
Результаты записываю в htm-отчет.
При попытке записать украинские или русские буквы браузер не отражает отчет правильно.
Если просто открывать отчет, как текстовый файл, то буквы видно правильно. Какую кодировку выбрать?

Answer (score 2):

Если в заголовке HTML вы правильно укажете кодировку файла, то браузер его правильно покажет.

А опус типа:

> Если просто открывать отчет, как текстовый файл, то буквы видно правильно.

просто говорит о том, что вы не понимаете, о чем пишете. Чем открываете, где открываете? Каждая "открывалка" по-своему понимает кодировку текстового файла (в зависимости от оси и проч. условий).

В общем, facepalm жесточайший.

Если речь идет о Linux, то, скорее всего, кодировка по умолчанию KOI-8 (тоже не факт, смотря какая кодировка у ваших исходников), чтобы это корректно отображалась под Windows, нужна кодировка Win-1251, чтобы браузер понимал и без спец. заголовка кодировки, лучше всего UTF-8 или ISO-8859-1 (и то в зависимости от оси).

**Update**

Все-таки рекомендовал бы UTF-8, согласно [отчету](http://w3techs.com/technologies/history_overview/character_encoding) - почти 82% сайтов используют кодировку UTF-8.

Comment: html-head: "<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=UTF-8\">"
отображение русских символов
Результат: http://savepic.org/6162169.png
google chrome 38.0.2125.101 m (64-bit)

Comment: @grodt, помимо указания меты, необходимо и логировать в этой кодировке. � - стандартный символ "null" в UTF-8, который вставляется в том случае, если декодировать не удалось.

А вообще, старайтесь свести к минимуму количество кириллицы и вставляемых имен в логах. Не знаю, как в вашем приложении, но у нас в вебе, как правило, можно без особого труда оставить айдишник.

Comment: @Etki, не подумал... к объекту класса FileHandler выполнил `setEncoding("UTF-8");`